# Variable is same among components in a map function (Next.js)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a map function going through my stories array [Map function image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj30n.png)

In each component, I have a function(deleteStory) that uses the story id variable [deleteStory function image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7agw9.png). Along with that, I have a button that calls the deleteStory function [button image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHtns.png).

The problem lies is when the deleteStory function runs, the storyId variable is the same for all components, when it should be unique to each component. [Debugging gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss9UC.gif)

Here is the code:

```
export default function stories()
{
const { data: stories, mutate: mutateStories } = findUserStoriesWithThemes();

return (
    <Container>
        <BootInnit/>

        {/* Bunch of code */}

        {stories?.story.map((story) => (
            <div key = {story.id}>
                <Story story = {story} storyUrl = {returnUrlStory} mutateStories = {mutateStories}/>
                <hr/>
            </div>
        ))}
    </Container>
});
```

Here is the stories component:

```
export default function Story({story, storyUrl, mutateStories}//mutateStories as in to refresh the feed
{
const storyId = story.id;

console.log(storyId);

const deleteStory = async() => {
    console.log(storyId);

    // DATABASE
}

return(
    <div>
        {/*Bunch of code*/}          
        <button className = "btn btn-danger" onClick = {deleteStory} type = "button" data-bs-dismiss = "modal">Delete</button>                  
    </div>   
);  
}
```

Comment: Please directly add images here, along with your code.

Comment: What does your stories array/object look like

Comment: Here is the stories array: [Stories array Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzLar.png)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that each model has the same id. So, the button that triggers the model were triggering all of them. Giving the illusion that all of the components had the same value.